# How to fix org.projectreactor vulnerabilities on Spring dependencies?

Tags: spring, maven, security, project-reactor

I discovered some vulnerabilities in a Spring project that use dependencies:

**reactor-netty-core**

**reactor-netty-http**

The only related import I have in the pom.xml file is:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectreactor</groupId>
    <artifactId>reactor-spring</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

After some research, I found that there is no new version for this dependency on [MavenRepository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.projectreactor/reactor-spring), but that there is another dependency with the same name (projectreactor).

The difference is that this dependency starts with ***.io*** instead of ***.org***.

https://projectreactor.io/docs/core

https://projectreactor.io/docs/netty

Can you help me to understand the difference between ***.io*** and ***.org*** in this case?

And what is the best way to update this to prevent these vulnerabilities?

Answer (score 0):

Have you *found* a vulnerability (as in security research) or do you get eg. tooling reporting a known vulnerability?

Both Spring projects and Reactor follow VMware [security policy](https://www.vmware.com/support/policies/security_response.html). If you've found vulnerabilities, this is the channel through which you should report them.

The `reactor-netty` artifacts are part of the 3rd generation of Project Reactor (the current one, with `io.projectreactor` base groupId).

The `org.projectreactor` groupId is for the 2nd generation. Reactor 2 is long discontinued (early 2015) and unsupported since then. Reactor 2 and 3 can basically be considered two entirely different libraries.

It is very weird that you'd have an application which uses `reactor-netty-*` and `reactor-spring` at the same time. If you are dealing with a Spring Framework 5 application, you can probably simply drop that dependency.